# Floating Action Button layout_margin(Bottom) has no effect on bottom margin

Tags: android, position, margin, android-relativelayout, floating-action-button

I am testing on an Android 6.0.1 device and the problem is that my FAB only reacts to layout_marginRight and not layout_marginBottom no matter which value I am using.

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewUnitNames"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"><!----></ScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    />      </RelativeLayout>
```

So if I align the FAB to the top left or top right corner, the margin works.
If I align it to the Bottom left or right corner, layout_marginBottom seems to have no effect.
I am using the design support library 23.2.0.
I tested it on an Android 4.0.3 emulator and it worked.
Do you have any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

**Edit** this is what it looks like:
[image]

**Edit 2**
I now know a little bit more: on create, I set the content view to an empty layout (only a relative layout inside). After some tests I change the layout like this:

```
RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
container.removeAllViews();
container.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout_file, null));
```

In a new project, I did the same and before I changed the layout it worked and after I changed it, it looked the same like on the image above. Is this an uncorrect way to change the layout? Or is there a better method? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have tried this layout on a Nexus 6 emulator running sdk 23 and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: yes, please read the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the xml for your `FloatingActionButton` to something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
      android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
      app:fabSize="normal"
      app:borderWidth="0dp"
      />
```

If you use `android:layout_margin` and `android:layout_marginBottom`, it will overwrite your bottom margin. Defining each margin by itself will allow you to have a different bottom margin than top/left/right.

**Updated answer:**

Change this line:

```
container.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout_file, null));
```

To

```
container.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout_file, container, false));
```

And it should correct the margin on the `FloatingActionButton`.

Comment: I don't want a different margin for the bottom than for the right margin. I was just testing if it works on different positions and I saw that only the bottom margin seems not to work. It's like layout_marginBottom is always zero.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing? I copy-pasted your layout and the bottom/right margins are both being respected.

Comment: Copy-pasted your layout xml into a test project and filled the `ScrollView` with a `LinearLayout` filled with `TextViews`, and got [this](http://i.imgur.com/zXH0TpK.png). My guess is there's something else in your layout or code that wasn't included here that is causing the margin change. Are you using a `CoordinatorLayout` with `app:layout_behavior` somewhere in your view hierarchy?

Comment: But to the scrollview I am adding a vertical linear layout and to this layout I am adding lots of horizontal linear layouts with this checkbox and textview.

Comment: Thank you so much! But this is a good way to change the layout, right?

Comment: It all depends on what you're doing. If you're completely changing the layout to a new view, you might as well use a new `Activity` or `Fragment`. If you're just changing the list of items in your `ScrollView`, you should look into using a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` instead.

Answer (score 1):

add this view at the bottom of the layout

```js
    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_16dp"
        android:layout_height="bottom margin of the floating action button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

and set the floating acton button over this view

```
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomView"
```